# Description of <build> section in pom.xml?

Tags: maven

Below is an  section of pom.xml :

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>test.group</groupId>
            <artifactId>test-artifact</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

What is this achieving ? Does this mean that when I deploy this project the groupId, artifactId & version parameter will be what is set in this section ?

Comment: This is made to specify that your project uses a plugin to perform some tasks during the build. Not sure to understand your question about deploying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The three elements `groupId`+`artifactId`+`version` serve as a unique identifier for an artifact in maven. In your case they specify the plugin named test-artifact. In order to know what this plugin is doing you will have to read the documentation of this particular plugin.

Most plugins will register some kind of keyword with maven, that you can use to execute this plugin, other plugins are executed as part of a phase. You can bind this plugin for example to the test-phase with

```
<phase>test</phase>
```

Unless this plugin binds to a certain phase by default, it will probably not be executed when you deploy your project.

For an example of the kind of keywords that plugins register with maven, take a look at the maven-exec-plugin [1], which registers the `exec:exec` and `exec:java` keywords to maven, such that you can run

```
mvn exec:exec
```

[1] http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/usage.html